# Wrapping text with npm XLSX package

Tags: javascript, excel, spreadsheet, xlsx, word-wrap

I am looking for a way to wrap text in a generated .xlsx document. I am using the npm xlsx package and angular with typescript.

here is an example of how I have been generating sheets so far...

const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet([], { skipHeader: true })
    XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, [{ title: "someTitle" }], { skipHeader: true, origin: "B2", })
    XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, [{ thing1: object.property }], { skipHeader: true, origin: "B3" })
    XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, [{ thing2: object.property }], { skipHeader: true, origin: "B4" })

return ws;

I need the the cell "B4" to wrap text so that it looks pretty for the user.

I have searched for some examples of this but to no solution found.

The xlsx-style package has a wrapped text property, but I would like to keep the packages to a minimum if at all possible.

Thank you!

Comment: It does support the same thing. See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#cell-object the `s` property of cell.

Comment: Do you have any examples? I guess I am just having difficulty understanding by reading the documentation.

Comment: That would be something like `cell.s = {alignment:{ wrapText: true }}`.